# Future of Asp.Net Dynamic Data

Tags: asp.net

Can anyone tell me what the future is for asp.net dynamic data?  It seems like it is being put aside in favor of MVC.  Is it worth investing time in dynamic data applications?

Comment: I think MVC and dynamic data are very different beasts. The first beeing a programming model, the second beeing a tool for another programming model (webforms). They can co-exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without branding, Dynamic Data applications can be created in minutes. It for your RAD webform developer who doesn't care about the UI layer. This would work well for just about intranet scenario. However, the MVC lineage is geared toward very different scenarios.

The Asp.net dynamic data entities web application compounds several layers into one. I know that Object Relational Mapping (ORM) is supposedly the future but when layers are not exposed, it can cause serious optimisation issues as well as making testing almost impossible. This is the case with both the ADO.NET Entity Framework (EF) model and the LINQ to SQL model. These are the only out of the box model providers availabe to Asp.net dynamic data entities web application. These do not work well, if at all with Microsoft Access.

However, when there is little time to architect a proper solution, Microsoft are ingenious when it comes to dirty ways to write applications. The dynamic data entities web is one such technology to add to their bow. You might be prepared to architect a Sql Server database roughly because you anticipate having to make changes to it later. If you want a quick know around website that you want to rip out later when you have more time Asp.net dynamic data entities web applications are for you? EF goes as far as foreign keys to definite relationships.

Comment: What's up with not just using MVC's scaffolding feature and a sane code-gen tool for creating views? Would it be so hard for MS to create a NHibernate + FluentNHibernate + MVC + autogen-DB/schemaexport + auto-update/schemaupdate + moq + a heap of documentation + a wizard to customize it all?

Comment: The issue I have with that is there is too much alt.net for my liking and therefore, for one, it would difficult to find someone with all those skills. This kind of defeats the point of doing RAD development, which is what this technology is about. In the log run, Microsoft catch up and the alt.net are no-longer needed. So, it is just easy using the available Microsoft technologies at the time. This is just a matter of opinion though.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it will die on the vine to me.

Answer (score 1):

Reference to my work before, asp.net dynamic data help me build a "quick + easy" data edit grid to user. I can customize the grid, configure to display what data to users.

But actually, aims of asp.net dynamic data is not purpose to do this.

On ASP.NET MVC 3.0, webgrid can generate by strong-type model with List or EF4.0 edmx ,it can do similar with asp.net dynamic data, so in my opinion, asp.net dynamic data has no future.